# bcrypt and randomly generated salts

Tags: php, salt, bcrypt, password-encryption

So I was experimenting with bcrypt. I have a class(shown below, which I got from http://www.firedartstudios.com/articles/read/php-security-how-to-safely-store-your-passwords) in which there are 3 functions. 1st one is to generate a random Salt, the 2nd to generate a hash using the 1st generated Salt and the last one is to verify the supplied password by comparing it with the hashed password.

```
<?php
/* Bcrypt Example */
class bcrypt {
    private $rounds;
    public function __construct($rounds = 12) {
        if(CRYPT_BLOWFISH != 1) {
            throw new Exception("Bcrypt is not supported on this server, please see the following to learn more: http://php.net/crypt");
        }
        $this->rounds = $rounds;
    }

    /* Gen Salt */
    public function genSalt() {
        /* openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16) Fallback */
        $seed = '';
        for($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++) {
            $seed .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
        }
        /* GenSalt */
        $salt = substr(strtr(base64_encode($seed), '+', '.'), 0, 22);
        /* Return */
        return $salt;
    }

    /* Gen Hash */
    public function genHash($password) {
        /* Explain '$2y$' . $this->rounds . '$' */
            /* 2a selects bcrypt algorithm */
            /* $this->rounds is the workload factor */
        /* GenHash */
        $hash = crypt($password, '$2y$' . $this->rounds . '$' . $this->genSalt());
        /* Return */
        return $hash;
    }

    /* Verify Password */
    public function verify($password, $existingHash) {
        /* Hash new password with old hash */
        $hash = crypt($password, $existingHash);

        /* Do Hashs match? */
        if($hash === $existingHash) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
/* Next the Usage */
/* Start Instance */
$bcrypt = new bcrypt(12);

/* Two create a Hash you do */
echo 'Bcrypt Password: ' . $bcrypt->genHash('password');

/* Two verify a hash you do */
$HashFromDB = $bcrypt->genHash('password'); /* This is an example you would draw the hash from your db */
echo 'Verify Password: ' . $bcrypt->verify('password', $HashFromDB);
?>
```

Now if I generate a hash with 'password' for example, I get a hashed password, which took the randmonly generated Salt. Next if I enter 'password' again and use the verify function ,I get true meaning that the passwords match. If I enter wrong password, I get false. My question is how is this possible? What about the randomly generated Salt? How come that is not having any effect?

Comment: PHP v5.5 (due out very soon) will have a set of `password_xxx()` functions that remove the need for any of this code. There's also a backward-compatibility library that you can download which implements those PHP 5.5 password functions into 5.3 or 5.4. You might want to try it; it'll save you a lot of work. See https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a good look at the values you're dealing with. The random salt generated will be, say:

```
abcdefg...
```

What is fed into `crypt` looks like this:

```
crypt($password, '$2y$10$abcdefg...')
                   |  |    |
                   |  |    +- the salt
                   |  +- the cost parameter
                   +- the algorithm type
```

The result looks like:

```
$2y$10$abcdefg...123456789...
 |  |    |        |
 |  |    |        +- the password hash
 |  |    +- the salt
 |  +- the cost parameter
 +- the algorithm type
```

In other words, the first part of the resulting hash is the same as the original input into the `crypt` function; it contains the algorithm type and parameters, **the random salt** and the hash result.

```
Input:  $password + $2y$10$abcdefg...
Output:             $2y$10$abcdefg...123456789...
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                   first part identical
```

When you confirm a password, you *need* the same, original salt again. Only with the same salt will the same password hash to the same hash. And it's still there in the hash, in a format that can be passed to `crypt` as is to repeat the same operation as when the hash was generated. That's why you need to feed both the password and hash into the validation function:

```
crypt($passwordToCheck, '$2y$10$abcdefg...123456789...')
```

`crypt` takes the first defined number of characters, up to and including `abcdefg...` and throws the rest away (that's why the salt needs to be a fixed number of characters). Therefore it equals the same operation as before:

```
crypt($passwordToCheck, '$2y$10$abcdefg...')
```

And will generate the same hash, **if and only if** `$passwordToCheck` is the same.

Comment: I understand that you will need the same salt again and the tutorial that I followed suggests to store that generated salt in the table along with the username and password. BUT, I tried it without using the original generated salt and it still works. I have tried it few many times and it works everytime.

Comment: Yes, because the salt **is part of the generated hash, in plaintext.** You don't need to store it separately, it's part of the hash. The first part of the hash is exactly the same as the parameter needed for `crypt`, which is why you simply feed it back into `crypt`.

Comment: So are you saying that bcrypt only checks that part of the hash that was created from the original password string and ignores the Salt, when verifying?

Comment: No, the opposite. Read my update. It reads the algorithm, cost and salt parts just like before and ignores the appended hash.

Comment: So bottom line is that, I just need to pass in the plain simple entered password from the user into the verify function, no need to add salt to it, or store the generated salt somewhere in the table when I hash the original password, say when registering the user?

Comment: When the user registers, you generate a salt and use it when hashing the password. The result is a string which contains all information necessary to reproduce the same result; you just store that one string in the database. You don't worry about the salt at all anymore, because the salt *is in that string*. When confirming the password, you just take that string out of the database and use it in the hash operation again with the newly entered password. You never generate a new salt for this particular password ever again.

Comment: As such, yes, I guess what you said is correct, though expressed backwards.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was a mystery to me until I got this great explanation from you. I understand it completely now. Thanks again.

Comment: Just one more quick question: If an attacker gets access to the database, he already knows that only the last part is from the password and the rest on the left is salt, so what is the point of having Salts then?

Comment: Lots of answers for this already: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt, http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33505/why-using-random-salts