# bcrypt salt for a password and cost

Tags: php, security, hash, bcrypt

I've just read about bcrypt and how good it really is. As I've understood, I was using salts along with other methods such as MD5,SHA1,SHA2 and so on, to prevent a rainbow attack. bcrypt requires a salt that tells it the cost.

I have few questions according to that:

1. Do I need to store a salt for each password in my DB? or I can just use the same salt for each password?
2. How does the cost work? what is the different between cost 15 and cost 20? I know that it has something with the iterations but what exactly does it do each iteration?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736119/bcrypt-and-randomly-generated-salts/16736254#16736254

Answer (score 3):

PHP's documentation is a bit misleading with the expression "salt", actually the `crypt()` function expects hash parameters, and the salt is just one part of this parameters.

The good thing is, that all the parameters will be included in the resulting 60 character hash-string, so you don't need to store them separately, just store the string and you are fine. The cost factor is raised to the power of 2, that means, increasing the cost factor by 1, will double the computing time.

PHP has now a function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) which handles all the difficult parts for you. Use this function instead of crypt, it will generate a safe random salt.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

I wrote a tutorial about this topic, if you are interested just have a look [here](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).