# password_hash function in php 5.5

Tags: php, password-hash, php-password-hash

i have the following function that hashes a password and stores it in a database. i am trying to use the password_hash function in php 5.5 but its giving me weird results.

```
function hashpass($password)
{
    include("includes/config.php");

    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    return $password;
}
```

I then output the result for the same static password which i am just testing as "testpassword" and it keeps giving me different hashes. Why is that? if it keeps doing that i will never be able to verify the password because it will never yield the same hash for the exact same string.

Is there something that i need to configure or set before hand for this to work correctly?

Comment: Because the hash generated includes a random salt each time. Use [`password_verify()`](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify the password.

Comment: the hash includes a randomly generated salt each time. a different salt for every hash is a GOOD thing. The salt is included in the hash string so it can be used for verification later.

Comment: Google `bcrypt`. Also [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) (return values section).

Comment: @Sammitch I'd suggest converting your comment to an answer. )

Comment: @Sammitch not only the salt but the algorithm and cost.

Comment: Salt is an awesome thing. if you give a $mypass to hash-core you get $somechars .$somechars can be used to guess the $mypass. however if you send $mypass+RandomSalt to hashcore even if the result is captured. it will not contain ideas about what is hashed at the begining

Comment: Just to add to the above, this is directly from the docs for [password_hash()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) `If omitted, a random salt will be generated by password_hash() for each password hashed. This is the intended mode of operation`.

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords. The guy who wrote the framework (SolarDesigner) is the same guy who wrote [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) and sits as a judge in the [Password Hashing Competition](http://password-hashing.net/). So he knows a thing or two about attacks on passwords.

Answer (score 4):

When you hash a password with `password_hash`, a **random salt** is being generated, used in the hashing process and prepended to the result. This is precisely for the purpose of avoiding the same passwords resulting in the same hash every single time; to avoid easy generation of rainbow tables. (All terms you should probably google. :))

To verify a hash generated with `password_hash` you need to use [`password_verify`](http://php.net/password_verify), which uses the salt embedded in the hash to reproduce and compare the hash from another plaintext password.

Comment: thank you for your help, im pretty knew to hashing and encryption so I didn't understand it very well, but thanks for the help

Comment: I (and others of course) have written about this a lot, look around a bit and you'll get it. For example, this may be a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22531422/476

Answer (score 2):

Hashes generated by `password_hash` (and most good password hashing algorithms) are salted. That means that an **extra set of random data is added to each password** before and sometimes during hashing.

A common format for password hashes is `##xxxxxxOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO`, where:

- `##` is the hashing algorithm identifier,
- `xxxxxx` is the salt, and
- `OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO` is the hashed password.

When comparing the stored hash with a given clear-text password, the algorithm will take the `##xxxxxx` part of the hash and use it to calculate a new password hash (say `##xxxxxxNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN`). It them compares the two hashes, and if they are equal, it can assume that the given clear-text password was the same as the initial password.

Because this differs from static hashes, you must use `password_hash` to initially hash the password on registration or password change, and [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/password_verify) to check if the given password is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, very insightful. Also i figured out what the issue was for me and what its not working, but i can';t figure is how to fix it. It seems that when i store the hash in the db and if there is "\" in the hash string it causes it the password_verify not to work for some reason. I confirmed that because i took a few hashes of the password until i found one that didn't have the "\" character in the string and you can see that it only fails only verifies on hashes without the "\". Not sure why though