# Add password_hash() to php with txt flatfile database

Tags: php, file, text, flat-file, php-password-hash

I am trying to understand how `password_hash()` function works.

I have got this ultra-simplified php login (completely unsafe, just designed to learn) with four passwords chosen by me.

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('pass.txt');

if($_POST['pass']) {
    $line = explode("\n", $data);
    for($i = 0; $i<count($line); $i++) {
        $item = explode("#", $line[$i]);
        if($_POST['pass'] == $item[0]) {
            echo "Welcome! You're logged in!";
        }
    }
}

else { echo '<form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="password" name="pass">
            <input type="submit">
            <form>';
}

?>
```

and this `pass.txt`, where the passwords are kept (.txt flatfile database):

```
passone
passtwo
passthree
passfour
```

**Is it possible to add password_hash() function to my code?**

I guess the php should be able to rewrite the database for this purpose, as this functions rewrites the passwords every time you login.

Thanks guys XXX

Comment: What's your exact doubt? If you hash passwords you'll store stuff like "$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a" instead of "passone". That's all, roughly.

Comment: Yes, but isn't it suposed to change every login? Should the php rewrite the txt file? I don't know how to write that :'(

Comment: use a predictable salt, like the username or something.   The hash will then be consistent which will allow you to compare.

Comment: @DevDonkey NO! No no no. Salts must be random. `password_hash` creates a random salt. Don't subvert that, it's missing the point of salts. You just need to use `password_verify` instead of `==`.

Comment: @deceze ahh, I didnt know such magic existed! cool :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.

oh, and you should use isset, else you might get PHP errors. and you should break; after finding a correct password, the rest is just a waste of cpu.

first for creating your pass.txt:

```
<?php
$passes=array(
'passone','passtwo','passthree'
);
foreach($passes as &$pass){
$pass=password_hash($pass,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}
file_put_contents("pass.txt",implode("\n",$passes));
```

then do like

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('pass.txt');

if(array_key_exists('pass',$_POST)){
    $lines = explode("\n", $data);
    for($i = 0; $i<count($lines); $i++) {
        if(password_verify($_POST['pass'],$lines[$i])) {
            echo "Welcome! You're logged in!";
            break;
        }
    }
}

else { echo '<form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="password" name="pass">
            <input type="submit">
            <form>';
}
```

- word of warning though. personally, i do not like password_hash, because its not easy to integrate with applications written in other languages (to c++ in my scenario), the hash structure is not clearly defined (as far as i know), short of reading the php interpreter's source code..

Comment: Looks really good but, should the passwords be written in the php file then? (line3 of your upper code)

Comment: where you get the passwords from is up to you.. grab it from a text file, a database, whatever. here, i just hardcode them in a php file, yes. go ahead, use $passes=file("unencrypted_passwords.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);  ^^

Comment: I'm trying your code. It's great. Is everything correct in the code which creates the passwords? It writes UNENCRYPTED passwords in the database. Shouldn't it write hashed codes and rewrite them on and on?

Comment: wups, i found a typo in the code, "foreach($passess as &$pass)" should'ev been "foreach($passes as &$pass)".. but the passwords should be encrypted/hashed in the database, yes.. and i tried the code myself, everything is hashed in the pass.txt, no plaintext passwords..

Comment: I'll give you the tick, it's a really great solution. Anyway, there should be a way to get rid of the plain passwords in the php, once they are witten in the database. shouldn't it?

Comment: @Kathlyn That's exactly the point of hashing passwords, you do not want to actually store the actual plaintext passwords. So just hash them once, and once you have a text file full of hashed passwords, delete the originals.

Comment: @deceze If i remove the plaintext, the code won't work, or at least, will stop "rewriting" the passwords in the database. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @hanshenrik if I generate a file to store unencrypted passwords... isn't that unsafe and ruins all the safety of password_hash()?

Comment: @Kathlyn Again, you're not supposed to hash the password every single time. That's a one time operation! Hash the password, store the hash, discard the original. Why hash passwords in the first place? Because you don't want to know or store the actual password!

Comment: @deceze Though you are a master in php compared to me, i think you are wrong in this case: The encrypted password in the database changes on and on through the time, automatically, (and keeps codifying the same plaintext). The encrypted password changes because this function changes the algorhythm time after time and that's why it is so safe. Try the code above and you will see... If i do it your way, it will work, but the algorhythm will still be the same forever and it won't be as safe.

Comment: @Kathlyn Sorry to say you have the wrong understanding of how password  hashing works and what it's good for. You hash passwords because you do not want to store the plaintext passwords, yet you still need a way to check a given password. Hashing a password is secure because a hash is a one-way function! It's not secure because it keeps changing, it's secure because you cannot reverse a hash to the plaintext. You do not need to keep changing the hashes in order for it to be secure. To keep changing the hashes, you need to store the plaintext password. [cont.]

Comment: @Kathlyn ... Storing the plaintext password obviously negates the use of password hashing in the first place (you do not want to store the plaintext password). It is as I say, I know that I know what I'm talking about here: you hash the password once, you only store the hash (which doesn't need to change), you use `password_verify` to verify a password against the hash, period.

Comment: So you mean that password_hash is the same as md5 or sha? But with a different language?

Comment: Do you agree with me that if you use the code above, the code in the database will change on and on with different encryptions of the passwords?

Comment: @Kathlyn Essentially yes, it is the same idea as MD5 (though it uses a stronger algorithm than MD5), *but* `password_hash` also adds a random salt, which is needed to prevent the use of rainbow tables (look that up). Random salts are necessary to prevent techniques which *can* lead to reversing a hash (again, look up brute-force hash cracking and rainbow tables).

Comment: @Kathlyn Yes, the code above re-hashes the passwords every time to some different hash. And again, to do that you need to store the plaintext passwords. And again, that's ludicrous, because it's missing the point of hashing and storing only hashes in the first place. The security of password hashing is not the process of hashing, it's the fact that **you don't store the plaintext password**, hence you don't *know* the plaintext password, hence the plaintext password cannot accidentally be leaked which would compromise your system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89913/discussion-between-kathlyn-and-deceze).

Answer (score 1):

1. Do `echo password_hash('passone')` for each of your passwords, store the resulting long gobbledygook string in your text file.
2. Instead of `if ($_POST['pass'] == $item[0])`,
   you do `if (password_verify($_POST['pass'], $item[0]))`.

That is, you use [`password_verify`](http://php.net/password_verify) on the plaintext password and a hashed password from your text file. `password_hash` creates a random salt during the hash process. **This random salt is part of the gobbledygook string it returns!** You need to reuse that random salt during the comparison. `password_verify` takes care of that for you.

That's all that's needed.

Comment: Thanks, it seems you understand me, but the password stored changes everytime you login and, under your approach, it wouldn't do it as it doesn't modify the flatfile database. (I don't know if I explained it clearly) XXX

Comment: See my update. You only **hash** the initial password once, from then on you use `password_verify`. You don't need to keep changing anything.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16736254/476 for an explanation of the underlying mechanism.

Comment: Thanks four your interest! Your answer was absolutely great but the other suited best my intentions. Maybe i didnt express correctly the question. I upvoted your answer too as I think it could be useful too. Thanks again xxx