# Login using PDO and SHA1

Tags: php, password-hash

I am new to PDO and I am a bit lost in the functions and how to make them work correctly!

I already created the functions to insert new users and now, I am trying to do the login function.

I crypted my password with this :

```
function create_salt($username,$timestamp)
{
    $hashed = sha1($username.$timestamp) ;

    $randomized = '';

    for ($i = 0 ; $i <= 40 ; $i++)
    {
        $randomChar = $hashed[rand(0, strlen($hashed)-1)];

        $randomized.=$randomChar;
    }

    return $randomized;
}
```

and for the user insert :

```
function userRegister($password,$email,$role,$title,$first_name,$last_name,$phone,$mobile_phone,$address,
                  $postal_code,$postal_case,$city,$country,$agent_number)
{
// generate username
$username = createUsername($first_name,$last_name,$email);

// create salt
$password_salt = create_salt($username,time());

// encrypt password
$cryptedPassword = sha1($password);

// create new pdo object
$pdo = dbConnect();

try
{
    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    // create the account, allowing the user to log in

    $req = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO t_accounts (a_creation,a_last_change,a_username,a_password,a_password_salt,a_email)
                VALUES (NOW(),NOW(),:username,:cryptedPassword,:password_salt,:email)");

    $req->execute(array(
        'username'          =>  $username,
        'cryptedPassword'   =>  $cryptedPassword,
        'password_salt'     =>  $password_salt,
        'email'             =>  $email
    ));

    echo 'Account added';

    $lastAccountID = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    // create the user

    $req2 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO t_users (t_roles_role_id,t_accounts_account_id,u_creation,u_last_change,
                u_title,u_first_name,u_last_name,u_phone,u_mobile_phone,u_address,u_postal_code,
                u_postal_case,u_city,u_country,u_agent_number)
                VALUES (:role,LAST_INSERT_ID(),NOW(),NOW(),:title,:first_name,:last_name,:phone,
                :mobile_phone,:address,:postal_code,:postal_case,:city,:country,:agent_number)");

    $req2->execute(array(
        'role'              =>  $role,
        'title'             =>  $title,
        'first_name'        =>  $first_name,
        'last_name'         =>  $last_name,
        'phone'             =>  $phone,
        'mobile_phone'      =>  $mobile_phone,
        'address'           =>  $address,
        'postal_code'       =>  $postal_code,
        'postal_case'       =>  $postal_case,
        'city'              =>  $city,
        'country'           =>  $country,
        'agent_number'      =>  $agent_number
    ));

    echo 'User added';

    $lastUserID = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    // open the logs for this account

    $req3 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO t_accounts_logs (al_date,al_ipv4,al_ipv6,al_description,al_username)
                VALUES (NOW(),:al_ipv4,:al_ipv6,:al_description,:al_username)");

    $req3->execute(array(
        'al_ipv4'           =>  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'al_ipv6'           =>  '',
        'al_description'    =>  'Création du user '.$lastUserID.'/'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.' avec le compte '.$lastAccountID.'/'.$username,
        'al_username'       =>  $username
    ));

    echo 'Log added';

    $pdo->commit();

    echo 'tout s\'est bien passé.';

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    // rollback the transaction
    $pdo->rollback();

    // display error message and datas
    echo 'Tout ne s\'est pas bien passé, voir les erreurs ci-dessous<br />';
    echo 'Erreur : '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
    echo 'N° : '.$e->getCode();

    // exit the catch to avoid the next errors
    exit();
}
}
```

and everything is working just fine.

Now, I am trying to do the login function and I need to check if the username, the email and the password are good.

Where I am :

```
function loginUser($fusername,$fpassword,$femail)
{
$pdo = dbConnect();

$encryptedPassword = sha1($fpassword);

// create the account, allowing the user to log in
try
{
    $req = $pdo->prepare("SELECT a_username, a_password, a_password_salt,a_email
                        FROM t_accounts WHERE t_accounts.a_username = :username
                        AND t_accounts.a_email = :email
                        AND t_accounts.a_password = :password;");

    $req->execute(array(
        ":username" => $fusername,
        ":email"    => $femail,
        ":password" => $encryptedPassword
    ));

    if ($req->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        while ($get = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
        {
            echo 'logged in';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'user does not exist';
    }

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "could not retrieve data from database" ;
}
}
```

I was looking for some tutorial like this one : https://x10hosting.com/community/threads/question-log-in-pages-with-pdo.192294/#post-923672 but he is not testing the password with the salt.

What should I change in the test if I need to check the salt too and is the function good?

Comment: For the love of god, please use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash).

Comment: @deceze : I userd $timestamp = time() ;

$password = 'password';

$options = [
    'cost' => 11 ,
    'salt' => create_salt($username,time())
];

$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
Is that what you want me to use now?

Comment: Don't create a salt manually with `password_hash`. Read the entire manual page. Then maybe read a little more here: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash

Comment: thank you for the link, I will read it entirely later, for now I really need to make this working with my actual function. I will have time to optimize it later.

Comment: It's not about "optimisation". If you want actual, secure password storage, your approach simply isn't good enough. Throw it away, use proven functions that work.

Comment: Ok, so I am reading the wiki page but everywhere, the salt is created manually, don't understand why you are telling me this and giving me this link, can you explain?

Comment: It *can* be specified manually and the examples show how to do it if necessary, but the manual explicitly states ***It is strongly recommended that you do not generate your own salt for this function. It will create a secure salt automatically for you if you do not specify one.***

Comment: Ok, still can't find it in the page but no problems. So, I juste have to create the hash with the same cost everytime I have to compare the password and no need to stock a salt in the database?

Comment: Indeed. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16736254/476 (`crypt` is the underlying implementation of `password_hash`).

Comment: while ($get = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
            {
                //$fpassword is the password from the form
                $hash = password_hash($get->a_password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,array("cost" => 11));
                if (password_verify($fpassword,$hash))
                {
                    echo 'correct password';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'incorrect password';
                }
            }
Did this after some edits into my functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final script, working fine, if someone needs it in the future

```
function userRegister($password,$email,$role,$title,$first_name,$last_name,$phone,$mobile_phone,$address,
                  $postal_code,$postal_case,$city,$country,$agent_number)
{
// generate username
$username = createUsername($first_name,$last_name,$email);

// encrypt password
$cryptedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 11));

// create new pdo object
$pdo = dbConnect();

try
{
    $pdo->beginTransaction();

    // create the account, allowing the user to log in

    $req = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO t_accounts (a_creation,a_last_change,a_username,a_password,a_email)
                VALUES (NOW(),NOW(),:username,:cryptedPassword,:email)");

    $req->execute(array(
        'username'          =>  $username,
        'cryptedPassword'   =>  $cryptedPassword,
        'email'             =>  $email
    ));

    echo 'Account added';

    $lastAccountID = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    // create the user

    $req2 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO t_users (t_roles_role_id,t_accounts_account_id,u_creation,u_last_change,
                u_title,u_first_name,u_last_name,u_phone,u_mobile_phone,u_address,u_postal_code,
                u_postal_case,u_city,u_country,u_agent_number)
                VALUES (:role,LAST_INSERT_ID(),NOW(),NOW(),:title,:first_name,:last_name,:phone,
                :mobile_phone,:address,:postal_code,:postal_case,:city,:country,:agent_number)");

    $req2->execute(array(
        'role'              =>  $role,
        'title'             =>  $title,
        'first_name'        =>  $first_name,
        'last_name'         =>  $last_name,
        'phone'             =>  $phone,
        'mobile_phone'      =>  $mobile_phone,
        'address'           =>  $address,
        'postal_code'       =>  $postal_code,
        'postal_case'       =>  $postal_case,
        'city'              =>  $city,
        'country'           =>  $country,
        'agent_number'      =>  $agent_number
    ));

    echo 'User added';

    $lastUserID = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    // open the logs for this account

    $req3 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO t_accounts_logs (al_date,al_ipv4,al_ipv6,al_description,al_username)
                VALUES (NOW(),:al_ipv4,:al_ipv6,:al_description,:al_username)");

    $req3->execute(array(
        'al_ipv4'           =>  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'al_ipv6'           =>  '',
        'al_description'    =>  'Création du user '.$lastUserID.'/'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.' avec le compte '.$lastAccountID.'/'.$username,
        'al_username'       =>  $username
    ));

    echo 'Log added';

    $pdo->commit();

    echo 'tout s\'est bien passé.';

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    // rollback the transaction
    $pdo->rollback();

    // display error message and datas
    echo 'Tout ne s\'est pas bien passé, voir les erreurs ci-dessous<br />';
    echo 'Erreur : '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
    echo 'N° : '.$e->getCode();

    // exit the catch to avoid the next errors
    exit();
}
}
```

And the second

```
function loginUser($fusername,$fpassword,$femail)
{
$pdo = dbConnect();

// create the account, allowing the user to log in
try
{
    $req = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *
                        FROM t_accounts WHERE t_accounts.a_username = :username
                        AND t_accounts.a_email = :email;");

    $req->execute(array(
        ":username" => $fusername,
        ":email"    => $femail
    ));

    if ($req->rowCount() == 1)
    {
        while ($get = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
        {
            //$hash = password_hash($get->a_password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,array("cost" => 11));

            if (password_verify($fpassword,$get->a_password))
            {
                echo 'Identifiants corrects';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Identifiants incorrects';
                echo "\r\n";
                echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"].'" />Retourner au formulaire</a>';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'user does not exist';
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo "could not retrieve data from database" ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to *select salt* along with hashed password, create a hash using that salt and then compare two hashes?

Comment: $timestamp = time() ;

$password = 'password';

$options = [
    'cost' => 11 ,
    'salt' => create_salt($username,time())
];

$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

echo $hash;

echo '<br />';

echo 'valeur de $password : '.$password.'  /  valeur de $hash : '.$hash ;

echo '<br />';

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo 'success';
}
else {
    echo 'failure';
}
I used this to test the logic, but I am lost when I have to put this on the login function.